# find the id of next row in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

lets say i have a table called tableTest which looks something like this

```
id |  name    | categoryID    
 1 |  test1   |          3    
 2 |  test2   |          6    
 3 |  test3   |          8    
 4 |  test4   |          3    
 5 |  test5   |          3
```

Now with the table above i first want to find only 1 row. The row with id 1.

```
SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE `id` = 1 AND `categoryID = 3;
```

So that will bring be back the first row. Now i need to find the ID of the next row ( ordering by id ) which has a categoryID of 3.

from the example above that would retrieve me row 4 as it is the very next  row that has the same categoryID.

How can i acheive this in mysql?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE categoryID = 3 order by id limit 1,1`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: you should have put this as an answer so it can be marked as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT id FROM testTable WHERE id > 1 AND categoryID = 3 GROUP BY categoryID

Answer (score 0):

You could order your results like this...

```
SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE `categoryID = 3 order by id ASC;
```

Which would return...

```
1
4
5
```

Or if you just wanted the id....

```
SELECT id FROM testTable WHERE `categoryID = 3 order by id ASC;
```

Or with a condition.....

```
SELECT id FROM testTable WHERE `categoryID = 3 AND id > 1 order by id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from testTable where id > 1 and categoryId = 3 limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with the simple query given as

```
select id 
from testTable 
where categoryID = '3' 
and id > (select id from testTable where id = '1' and categoryID ='3' ) 
order by id iimit 1
```